# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;

Tags: android

I am working on an app which has got In app purchases and there is a restore button to restore  the purchased goods even after the user uninstalls or deletes the app. I was successful in making the in app purchase and now I found few examples to work on the restore button.

I implemented it and followed the procedure to get the signed apk but there appears an error everytime I try to do that.

Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;

I am having IMarketBillingService.aidl and IInAppBillingService.aidl in the package named com.android.vending.billing which when the project is built generate IMarketBillingService.java and IInAppBillingService.java in the gen folder. But at the run time I get the above error and I am not able to pass through this, I followed deleting the bin and gen folder from the source code and then cleaning the code but still the same problem persists. Please help me to solve this problem.

**EDIT**: 
I think this might be the reason for this to happen.
I got the IInAppBillingService.aidl file from my friend and that way I didn't install it. Now, I am trying to install it through Android SDK Manager but I am not able to approach to Extras here, all i can see is the screen having the options like:

Virtual Devices
Installed Packages
Available Packages

How can I appraoch Extras here so that the aidl file gets installed.

I tried to open the SDK Manager by:

1. Opening SDK Manager.exe file at the root of the Android SDK directory.
2. By using the path, Window > Android SDK Manager in the Eclipse.

Am I doing anything wrong here to find the Extras to install the aidl file, Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The billing library is getting included twice. Either one of your dependencies is already including it or you have the library dependency twice.

Comment: Thanks Delyan, but how can I resolve it, can you be more specific on this, Please help.

Comment: How did you add the billing library to your app? Library project or straight copy & paste?

Comment: @Delyan I copied the billing library (and by that you mean IMarketBillingService.aidl and IInAppBillingService.aidl) to the package com.android.vending.billing in the src folder and then after building the project the IMarketBillingService.java and IInAppBillingService.java gets generated in the res folder with same   name of the package (com.android.vending.billing), am I doing anything wrong here, please specify.